# Optimization of faceted navigation and pagination

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I recently launched a store under Magento and I would like to improve both faceted navigation and pagination.

- Faceted navigation : Do you know a module that avoids reloading the page each time a filter is activated and disables the generation of url with parameters?
- Pagination: Do you know a module that allows to suppress navigation, display products as the user scrolls and that makes accessible all the products urls from the source code of the page to optimize the crawl of robots such as Google?

Thank you in advance for your help.